# Utilizing different filegroups on SQL Server to mitigate Error Msg 1105, Level 17, State 2, Line 5

Tags: sql-server, runtime-error, diskspace

The error I need help with is this:

> Msg 1105, Level 17, State 2, Line 5
>   Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.SUBPART_P6' in database 'PROFILEDB' because the 'FG3' filegroup is full. Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.

I am trying to utilize filegroups other than the default primary filegroup. I created a couple of filegroups (fg2 and fg3) and utilized them in my code. The problem I am facing is that when fg2 (fg2.mdf) is filled up to 9 GB (9042944 KB), then my code moves on to write data to fg3 (fg3.mdf). But the code stops again by Error 1105 saying my fg3 is full. I can see that the size of fg3.mdf on disk is 354 MB (354304 KB). The initial size of each filegroup (after creation) was roughly 5 MB.

I am using SQL Server 2014 Express edition. I have 11.4 GB of space left (after error 1105) on my C drive where SQL Server is setup. So, I have enough storage space left on my C drive for the task. When my code was using the primary filegroup, it used to get up to about 10 GB before returning Error 1105.
Also all the files have autogrowth ON.

I need to know why fg3.mdf stops at 354 MB while fg2.mdf stopped at 9 GB?

I would appreciate possible solutions or hints. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you set a max size on your data file? You didnt' post the DDL so we don't know.

Comment: Many google searches indicate the max size of a SQL Express database is 10G.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thanks!

Comment: I need to look for another technology, I am going to try Postgres and see how that handles my files.

Comment: Have you tried creating a clustered column store index against your largest table? This can compress the table by varying amounts (typically up to 10x). There might be rewriting and migration required to move to Postgres

Comment: You can also split your data into multiple databases.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid this is a very good suggestion! I wonder if it's possible to create and use a new database from within a stored procedure? probably not but I have to try it first to see if I can make it work or if it's too much to ask! hehe... I am importing several csv files into sql server by dynamically creating tables so they are not too big. I guess for my purpose I can separate them among different databases as you suggeted! Thanks!

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I have to look in to column store index as well. Thanks for your suggestions again!

Comment: I got the idea of parameterizing the @DB name from another place. Now I can import a lot more data spread out in 3 databases. The disk space left (on C) is 200 MG so I need to re-run the procedure. This whole thing eating up more than 25 GB! I looked into columnstore index and I'm afraid it may not work out for me because in my case I have csv's with a lot of duplicate information per row, or in fact, columns!

Comment: I suggest not over-complicating it. Just identify a logical seperation of data and do it that way. It's really easy to try out the columnstore index. Just create it.